# creating order queue based on starttime and endtime in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that contains four date columns, a starttime and an end time and date column that defines a range. I'd like to be able to collectively create a queue count for all time and date across all rows in the data frame, as defined by these columns.

```
date start

 1. date   starttime   endtime  storeid
 2. 2/3/20  6:20 pm    7:20 pm   12231
 3. 2/3/20   6:25pm    7:25 pm  12231
 4. 2/3/20   6:29pm    7:40 pm   12231
 5. 2/3/20   7:21pm    7:59pm    12231
6.  2/3/20   6:21pm    7:21 pm   12232
```

I wants to generate queue based column that will give me how many queue are there before the current one in below way:

```
date start

 1. date   starttime   endtime  storeid queue 
 2. 2/3/20  6:20 pm    7:20 pm  12231     1
 3. 2/3/20   6:25pm    7:25 pm  12231     2
 4. 2/3/20   6:29pm    7:40 pm  12231     3
 5. 2/3/20   7:21pm    7:59 pm  12231     2
 6. 2/3/20   6:21pm    7:21 pm  12232     1
```

I am new to this and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of a queue at any point is a step function.  There is a package called [staircase](https://staircase.dev), which is built on pandas and numpy, for step functions.  It even has a [queue analysis case study](https://www.staircase.dev/en/latest/case_studies/queues.html).

**setup**

Using a slightly different format of your data (it's easier to work with, I'd encourage you to use it)

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "start":[
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 18:20"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 18:25"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 18:29"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 19:21"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 18:21"),
        ],
        "end":[
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 19:20"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 19:25"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 19:40"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 19:59"),
            pd.Timestamp("2020-03-02 19:21"),
        ],
        "storeid":[12231,12231,12231,12231,12232]
    }
)
```

this gives you

```
                start                 end  storeid
0 2020-03-02 18:20:00 2020-03-02 19:20:00    12231
1 2020-03-02 18:25:00 2020-03-02 19:25:00    12231
2 2020-03-02 18:29:00 2020-03-02 19:40:00    12231
3 2020-03-02 19:21:00 2020-03-02 19:59:00    12231
4 2020-03-02 18:21:00 2020-03-02 19:21:00    12232
```

**solution**

We can create a `Stairs` object, which represents a step function for the entire queue across both stores, like so

```
import staircase as sc

sc.Stairs(data, "start", "end")
```

Since we want a queue per store we can use a groupby to create a `Stairs` object for each store

```
stepfunctions = data.groupby("storeid").apply(sc.Stairs, "start", "end")
```

`stepfunctions` will be a `pandas.Series` indexed by store, whose values are `Stairs` objects

```
storeid
12231    <staircase.Stairs, id=2640536293576>
12232    <staircase.Stairs, id=2640538596168>
dtype: object
```

You can do lots of things with these `Stairs` objects including plotting

```
stepfunctions[12231].plot(style="hlines")
```

[image: step function for queue at store 12231]

You can also add them together to create the combined queue

```
stepfunctions[12231] + stepfunctions[12232]
# or
stepfunctions.sum()
```

You can sample the queue size at any point(s) you like.  It seems like you want the queue size sampled at each start time.  For store 12231 you can do this like so

```
stepfunctions[12231](data["starts"])
```

which gives you

```
array([1, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64)
```

In order to get add this column to your dataframe it will be easier to do this in the same step as creating the step function in the groupby-apply.

**So the entire solution (after imports) is**

```
def queue_count_sample(df):
    sf = sc.Stairs(df, "start", "end")
    df["queue"] = sf(df["start"])
    return df

data.groupby("storeid").apply(queue_count_sample)
```

**note:** I am the creator of staircase. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!!! I was looking for this for a while. I am unable to visualise it but that is not important queue is working the way I wanted.this is time efficient as well. I have another column of store id that I do need to verify if it's same or not. Can we pass that in stairs function or we have to loop the step function ?

Comment: I might need you to add an example, to your original question, of what you mean about the store id column.

Comment: I have updated the question. I really appreciate your support.

Comment: Ok, so different queues for each store?

Comment: yes different queue for each store

Comment: ok I'll update the answer

Comment: @prashant updated